# How to place buttons inline in Facebook messenger bot?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Sometimes need to arrange the buttons in a line.

For example, if we send 8 buttons with short text they will appear  like this:

1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8

Is it possible to place buttons in a line in the screen area without scrolling to the right:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide a screenshot of how they appear ? For me 'quick replies' always appear horizontal.
Thanks